# Error:(387, 5) error: resource color/colorPrimary (aka com.example.kubix.r3vir3dv3:color/colorPrimary) not found

Tags: android, colors

I'm a beginner and it's about converting this code or defining colors.Can anyone help me with this?

```
<style name="Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/abc_alert_dialog_material</item>
    <item name="listLayout">@layout/abc_select_dialog_material</item>
    <item name="listItemLayout">@layout/select_dialog_item_material</item>
    <item name="multiChoiceItemLayout">@layout/select_dialog_multichoice_material</item>
    <item name="singleChoiceItemLayout">@layout/select_dialog_singlechoice_material</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**res/values/color/color.xml** create a color with name of **colorPrimary**

Comment: Thant is fine Thank you so much.