# Android error: AAPT: error: resource color/colorPrimary not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgraded my project ( Ionic Framework ) from Android to AndroidX. After that, my project started throwing errors while rebuilding. **It is giving "AAPT: error: resource color/colorPrimary (aka io.aide.aide:color/colorPrimary) not found." from file "{Project}\android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml"**.

Here is my `styles.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The folder of styles.xml is as below

[image]

In the below post, they suggested to create a color file.
[Error:(387, 5) error: resource color/colorPrimary (aka com.example.kubix.r3vir3dv3:color/colorPrimary) not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382665/error387-5-error-resource-color-colorprimary-aka-com-example-kubix-r3vir3d)

I am beginner and I do not know what should be in the color file.

Can any one give me any suggestions to overcome this problem?

Comment: can you share colors.xml file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your project, you need to create **color.xml** file

> Right click on values > New > Values Resource File > Enter File Name "color.xml"

**Path**:

```
 res/values/color.xml
```

This is how your **color.xml** will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_1</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_1</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">@color/blue_5</color>

    <color name="blue_1">#00101f</color>
    <color name="blue_5">#0078ff</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my problem. Finally, I am able to upgrade my project to AndroidX and build it without errors.

Comment: for me, the color.xml had to go straight to /values folder

Comment: My file is colors.xml

but the hashtable records are
 <color>   ...   <color>   ,<!-- and can reference other <color> items if they precede-->

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the color resources in res/values/colors.xml to avoid the error.

Example :

- for `@color/colorPrimary` write the following code in res/values/colors.xml
  `<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>`
- for `@color/colorPrimaryDark` write the following code in res/values/colors.xml
  `<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>`
- for `@color/colorAccent` write the following code in res/values/colors.xml
  `<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>`